# ask the user if a sequence of two letters is in a random array of letters

Tags: c++

The user inputs some desired length of a string of characters . then the program outputs a list of randomly generated characters. After which the user is prompted to input 2 characters (that either exist or does not exist whiten the list). the program will then output where the first character appears in the pair or say that the pair does not exist in the list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int size, c;
    char ltr1, ltr2;
    cout << "How many letters do you want in your random sting? ";
    cin >> size;
    string str;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        c = rand() % 26 + 'a';
        str.push_back(c);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << str[i];
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << "what pair of letters would you like to find?";
    cin >> ltr1;
    cin >> ltr2;
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (char((str[i] == ltr1) && (str[i + 1] == ltr2)))
        {
            cout << "the pair is in the string starting at character number "
                 << i << " in the string" << endl;
        }
        if (char((str[i] == ltr1) && (str[i + 1] != ltr2)))
        {
            cout << "the pair " << ltr1 << ltr2 << " is not in the string." << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the output is capable of determining weather or not the pair exist or not and will output the location however if you input a value greater than 25 it will run the final output multiple times.

Comment: Define "run the final output multiple times". What does this mean? Yes, there are several obvious bugs in the shown code, but it's unclear what your actual question is.

Comment: You should check out some [good documentation for the `std::string` member functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). Odds are good you'll find at least one function that does exactly what you need.

Comment: I ran your code, and I think your'e asking how to stop printing that the pair is in the list multiple times yes? i.e. once it finds a pair it prints it and then exits?

Comment: To reiterate, if there are multiple occurrences of the pair, do you want to print every occurrence or just the first? Regardless you might get the "is not in string" message multiple times because this triggers every time the first letter of the pair is found but the next doesn't match.

Comment: Have you tried [explaining every line in your program to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)? Remember the Golden Rule Of Computer Programming: "A Computer Always Does Exactly What You Told It To Do, Instead Of What You Want It To Do". Now, write out in plain English (or your native language), exactly what you told your computer to do with your `for` loop, and read it outloud to your rubber duck, and your bug should be very obvious.

Comment: which for loop are you refering too

Comment: Again *do you want it to print every occurrence or just the first*? If you answer this then we know what you're going for and can better help you get there. The rubber duck is a great suggestion too.